# HTML and JQuery for animating a n-by-n grid of boxes or tiles

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I would like to create a layout using HTML 5, CSS, jQuery (animate) like the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBpAJ.jpg.    I would like to animate the transition between multiple arrangements of the tiles. For example between a set of tiles or boxes like this to a similar set of boxes or tiles likethis https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKHjL.jpg. (For purposes of illustration the second image is just a rotation of the first, but we We can expect any combination and organization of the boxes/tiles).

The animation should be triggered by a button press and should be reusable since there are potentially an infinite number of ways to organize the boxes. I want the transition to work like this: each box moves off towards the right side of the screen on an independant path while the new boxes move in from the left on their own independant paths. I would like the entire animation to be constrained to its own div so that it doesn't interfere with other elements on the page (navigation bars etc). A final constraint is I want this to work in most modern browsers (and ideally IE 8 and 9 as well).

What is the most graceful way to markup the boxes (both sets)? What is a good animation function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by having a look at [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co), it has lots of sorting and animations for grid-based content.

Check out the demos, especially the part about [adding elements](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/adding-items.html). It seems to be the effect you're going for.

You might need to "trick" it to look like your proposed layout by adding empty/transparent items.